# Как отнять 1 от всех чисел в списке, одной строкой?

Tags: python, массивы

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_list[:] -= 1
print(my_list)
```

Comment: `[x - 1 for x in my_list]`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 6):

Я тоже украду комментарий у ZxNuClear:

> ```
> my_list = [x - 1 for x in my_list]
> ```

У решения есть мелкий недостаток. Вернее два: `my_list` меняет `id` в процессе обновления (что иногда полезно и важно, а иногда вредно и ломает программу) и создаётся копия списка в памяти.

Сохранить `id` можно так (автор вопроса использовал эту конструкцию, значит он хочет сохранить объект?):

> ```
> my_list[:] = [x - 1 for x in my_list]
> ```

Копирование останется. Пробуем удалить и его:

> ```
> my_list[:] = (x - 1 for x in my_list)
> ```

Кажется что не нужна память под список в правой части присваивания, но нет, нужна. `my_list[:] = [...]` и `my_list[:] = (...)` делают одно и тоже. В коде Питона сделано так что если слева `список[:]` а справа не список (или другой контейнер с известной длиной), то генератор из правой части копируют в список. Копия осталась на месте, несмотря на изменение в коде. :(

Но "я хоть попытался..." - Пролетая над гнездом кукушки.

Comment: ну, ваш ответ точно кражей не является, так как детально объясняет решение и предлагается альтернатива, а не просто `ctrl+c` и `ctrl+v` ))

Comment: @ZxNuClear, спасибо!

Comment: круто приписали мне кражу, я даже не смотрел в его комментария что он что то писал

Answer (score 2):

**1 способ**

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_list = [x - 1 for x in my_list]
```

**2 способ**

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x - 1, my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

есть такое приходится делать часто, используйте `numpy`

```
import numpy as np


arr = [7, 5, 9, 0]
arr = np.array(arr)
arr -= 1
print(arr)
```